Как в Power Bi Desktop обращаться в результату запроса
Есть два запроса (обычная выборка). Хочу во втором запросе получить первую строку первого запроса.
Запросы создавал так: Создать источник->SQL Server
1 запрос называется Users
во втором запросе пытаюсь получить первую строку первого запроса = Sql.Database("","",[Query="SELECT " & Text.From(Users{0})])
Получаю ошибку:

Не удалось преобразовать значение типа Record в тип Text

Подскажите как в Power BI Desktop обратиться к другому запросу?
